# upgrade jquery 1.10.2 to 3.1.1 Kendo events not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have an existing application that is a MVC4 .net application, it is using server side Kendo components, the jquery version that it currently has is 1.10.2 now I want to migrate it to latest jquery version(3.1.1) but the events

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor().Events(e => e.Change("onChangeInvestigationTypeCode"))
```

are broken after the migration. The error I am receiving on browser is onChangeInvestigationTypeCode is not defined.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What version of kendo are you using?(https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history) I am asking because I use the same version of jQuery and the latest in Kendo and I don't have this issue.

Comment: I am using v2017.3.1026, i got it worked my removing all unused references to older kendo libraries